# como agrego la formula HOY() para programar una validación de datos entre dos fechas en apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

tengo la siguiente duda y es que tengo una tabla en la que se agregan fallas ocurridas en estaciones (es para un proyecto del trabajo), la primera fecha a agregar es la del escalamiento de la falla, la segunda fecha es la de atención, esta fecha quiero que sea entre la fecha de escalamiento y hoy, porque obviamente no se puede decir que se atendió una estación a futuro.

La cosa es que, al crear la validación de los datos, fácilmente puedo agregar entre los dos valores la celda por ejemplo '=D10' y en el otro campo puedo colocar la formula '=HOY()', lo cual es una solución perfecta, pero como estoy haciendo un formulario que agrega y crea estas validaciones de forma automática en apps script, me he encontrado con el siguiente problema, pues al grabar la macro para ver cómo funcionaba las validaciones, me entrega el siguiente resultado en codigo:

```
spreadsheet.getRange('H10').setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
  .setAllowInvalid(false)
  .setHelpText('Introduce una fecha entre el =D10 y el =HOY()')
  .requireDateBetween(new Date(1899, 11, 30), new Date(1899, 11, 30))
  .build());
```

Cómo se puede observar en las dos fechas el propio macro registra lo del 'D10' y el 'HOY()' en su descripción, no obstante, en las fechas a utilizar esta usa en ambos '1899, 11, 30'. Ya modifiqué el código de la siguiente manera (probando con otra celda):

```
var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var form= ss.getSheetByName('REGISTRAR_FALLA')

  form.getRange('H11').setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().setAllowInvalid(false).setHelpText('Introduce una fecha entre el =D10 y el =HOY()').requireDateBetween(new Date(form.getRange('D11').getValue()), new Date()).build());
```

De esta forma el agarra el valor de la celda 'D11' como inicio, y como fecha límite la fecha de """hoy""" y lo pongo entre comillas porque realmente es la fecha de hoy y solo hoy, por lo que mañana ya no será la fecha de hoy. Adjunto fotos de cómo queda en la pestaña de validaciones:

[Validación hecha con el propio google sheets y validación hecha con apps script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyxGl.png)

Entonces lo que quisiera saber ahora es si existe alguna forma de poder colocar la formula 'HOY()' dentro de la condicional para que siempre este actualizado, gracias por leer mi problemática de antemano jaja.